# Android java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null on customAdapter

Tags: java, android, fragment, custom-adapter

Am trying to create an app using fragments.
The problem I'm experiencing is that I want to switch between 2 fragments but its not working. The first fragment (Continental List fragment) contains a list, when this is clicked, I want the screen to switch to the second fragment (Meals Fragment) which also contains a list generated using a custom adapter. I have achieved this using activities (Intents) but I understand this does not work with fragments.

MainActivity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ContinentalListFragment.OnListSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bu`enter code here`ndle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public void OnListSelected(int index) {

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+index,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    ContinentalMealsFragment mealsFragment = (ContinentalMealsFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
    if (mealsFragment != null) {
        mealsFragment.setIndex(index);
    } else {

        ContinentalMealsFragment newMealFragment = new ContinentalMealsFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ContinentalMealsFragment.ARG_POSITION, index);
        newMealFragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment1, newMealFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
        newMealFragment.setIndex(index);

    }

}
}
```

Custom Adapter

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.Image;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private final String[] meals;
private final String[] prices;
private final int[] icon;

public CustomAdapter(Activity context, int resource, String[] meals,   String[] prices, int[] icon){
    super(context, resource, meals);
    this.meals = meals;
    this.prices = prices;
    this.icon = icon;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View rowView = convertView;
    ViewHolder view;

    if(rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.meal_item, null);

        view = new ViewHolder();
        view.meal_name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.food_name);
        view.meal_price = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.food_price);
        view.meal_logo = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.food_img);

        rowView.setTag(view);
    } else {
        view = (ViewHolder)rowView.getTag();
    }

    String m=meals[position];
    String p=prices[position];
    int i=icon[position];
    view.meal_name.setText(m);
    view.meal_price.setText(p);
    view.meal_logo.setImageResource(i);

    return rowView;
}

protected static class ViewHolder{
    protected ImageView meal_logo;
    protected TextView meal_name;
    protected TextView meal_price;

}
}
```

Meals Fragments 2

```
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ContinentalMealsFragment extends Fragment {
// String array of food name and prices in Italian
private CustomAdapter adapter = null;
private String dish[];
private String prices[];
private int icon_id[] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
private TypedArray icon;
private int index = 4;
final static String ARG_POSITION = "position";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.meal_item, container, false);


    return view;
}


public void setMenus(int index) {

    switch (index) {

        case 0:
            dish = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.asianMenu);
            prices = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.asianPrice);
            icon = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.asianIco);
            for (int i = 0; i < icon.length(); i++) {
                icon_id[i] = icon.getResourceId(i, -1);

            }


        case 1:
            dish = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.frenchMenu);
            prices = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.frenchPrice);
            icon = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.frenchIco);
            for (int i = 0; i < icon.length(); i++) {
                icon_id[i] = icon.getResourceId(i, -1);
            }

        case 2:
            dish = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.mexicanMenu);
            prices = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.mexicanPrice);
            icon = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.mexicanIco);
            for (int i = 0; i < icon.length(); i++) {
                icon_id[i] = icon.getResourceId(i, -1);
            }

        case 3:
            dish = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.italianMenu);
            prices = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.italianPrices);
            icon = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.italianIco);
            for (int i = 0; i < icon.length(); i++) {
                icon_id[i] = icon.getResourceId(i, -1);

            }

    }

}

public void setIndex(int index) {
    this.index = index;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setIndex(index);
    setMenus(index);


}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    ArrayAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.meal_item,dish,prices,icon_id );
    ListView mealFrag = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mealFrag);
    mealFrag.setAdapter(customAdapter);
}
}
```

Meals XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/food_img"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/index"/>


<TextView
    android:text="Food Name"
    android:id="@+id/food_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/food_price"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/food_img"
    android:textSize="32dp" />

<TextView
    android:text="price"
    android:id="@+id/food_price"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="32dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mealFrag" />
```

Continental List Fragment

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class ContinentalListFragment extends Fragment {

    private OnListSelectedListener mCallBack;
    private int index;

    public interface OnListSelectedListener {
        public void OnListSelected(int index);
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);


        try {
            mCallBack = (OnListSelectedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnListSelectedListener");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.continental_list, container, false);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.continental, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        ListView listFrag = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listFrag);

        listFrag.setAdapter(adapter);
        listFrag.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                                mCallBack.OnListSelected(position);
                                            }
                                        }
        );
        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }


}
```

I received this error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tkk3468.androidapp/com.tkk3468.androidapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null
        at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:38)
        at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:155)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:128)
        at com.tkk3468.androidapp.CustomAdapter.<init>(CustomAdapter.java:21)
        at com.tkk3468.androidapp.ContinentalMealsFragment.onActivityCreated(ContinentalMealsFragment.java:97)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1797)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:979)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1120)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1929)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:547)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1236)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6006)
        at 

android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
08-26 19:39:48.576    5356-5356/? I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 5356 SIG: 9
```

Is there any solution that would allow me to achieve this easily?
I appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Probably your `dish` is null while constructing the CustomAdapter object?

Comment: Ive put all my array inside strings.xml and populate the customadapter inside the meals fragment